# Data factory: how to execute query after copy from blob to SQL?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to schedule copy pipeline from blob to SQL.
Is there way to run a custom query after the copy is done (e.g. creating/updating view in SQL database)?

Does sqlWriterCleanupScript run before or after the copy is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlWriterCleanupScript runs as the first step but only for the re-runs of the copy activity. If you want to run a custom query post copy activity then use the stored procedure activity as https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-stored-proc-activity/ .

Comment: stored procedure activity requires a output table. What am I  supposed to put in that table if the first activity has already copied. It  can't be the same as the first activity. This doesn't make  sense as the stored procedure specifies all of the tables that it uses and  doesn't need anything. The stored procedure should be able to run independently from the activity as a post, run cleanup script. Shouldn't there be some way to simply execute the stored procedure?

Comment: @billmanH Azure data factory requires every activity have an output dataset, even in the case that the activity doesn't really result in a new dataset. The docs suggest you create a fake dataset that doesn't represent an actual resource and specify the fake dataset as the output of the activity (stored procedure in your case). The argument for requiring this fake dataset output is that it is what you use to control the scheduling of the activity execution.

Comment: Do you know if sqlWriterCleanupScript still works in ADF V2? I ran the ADF Migration wizard from V1 to V2 and it looks like it is in the JSON but NOT in the UI.